# How do I convert Twitter data to csv file?

Tags: r, csv, twitter, rtweet

I am analyzing Twitter data and are using the `rtweet` package to access the data I need. Mostly it's working fine, and I get the tweets that I want. My problem is, that I need to convert the data to a csv file so I can open it in Excel.

I tried using the following code to save as csv, but when I open it in Excel it's all messed up. `write_as_csv(denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic, file_name = "DK1tweets.csv", prepend_ids = TRUE, na ="", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
save_as_csv(denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic, file_name="DK1tweets.csv", prepend_ids = TRUE, na = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`

Until now I have the data downloaded through the commands shown below. I hope someone has the answer to my problems :)

```
#timeline for denmarkdotdk
denmarkdotdk <- get_timeline("@denmarkdotdk", n=3200)
denmarkdotdk

#remove retweets
denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic <- denmarkdotdk[denmarkdotdk$is_retweet==FALSE,] 

#remove replies
denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic <- subset(denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic, is.na(denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic$reply_to_status_id))
denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic
```

Comment: What locale is your Excel? E.g. in some European countries the separator is a ";" and not a comma (",").

Comment: I'm located in Denmark. I tried na = ";" now, but it does not seem to help. I read somewhere that it need to be converted into a data frame, before I can convert it into a readable csv. but after having tried several methods I still can't get it to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by 'messed up'? You can check if you have a dataframe with `class(denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic)`.

Comment: When looking at the data in R, it looks perfectly organized with the correct rows and columns. But when I open the csv file the data is located all kind of random places. The rows and columns are gone and the data is scattered all over the file

Comment: Have you tried `write.csv` and its sibling `write.csv2`?

Comment: When writing `class(denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic)` I get the following information: `[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`. I'm not sure whether that means I have a data frame or not. I tried write.csv like this `write.csv(denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic,"denmarkdotdktwitter.csv")` but get the following error ```error in write.table(denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic, "denmarkdotdktwitter.csv", 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'```

Comment: It looks like you have a dataframe, but where one or more of your columns is a list. I'm not so familiar with`rtweet`, but it sounds like you have to somehow flatten or restrict your object `denmarkdotdk_tweets_organic` further.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775074/write-tweets-from-rtweets-package-to-csv

Comment: Thank you! But I end up with the same issue - the write.csv command gives me an error every time

Answer (score 0):

Please retry your data download with:

```
library(rtweet)
df <- search_tweets("@denmarkdotdk", n = 3200, include_rts = FALSE, retryonratelimit = TRUE)     #no retweets included
save_as_csv(df, "df.csv", prepend_ids = TRUE, na = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

..and using your method also works with:

```
library(twitteR)
#timeline for denmarkdotdk
denmarkdotdk <- get_timeline("@denmarkdotdk", n=3200)
df <- as.data.frame(denmarkdotdk)
head(df)
#remove retweets
df1<- df[df$is_retweet==FALSE,] 
head(df1)
df2 <- df1[df1$reply_to_status_id=="NA",]
dim(df2)
head(df2)
df3  <- subset(df1,is.na(df1$reply_to_status_id))  # -replies
head(df3)
dim(df3)

save_as_csv(df3,"df3.csv",prepend_ids = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your method. However, the rtweet code line also downloads tweets that are not from the timeline of the profile denmarkdotdk. I have tried with TwitteR too, but it cannot process content in the tweets such as emojis...

Comment: You may need to filter after downloading / manage the keyword -see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/rtweet.pdf. rtweet works as shown above, it is the better package currently - see usage details, filtering and comparison of features: https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet. If this/above is useful, please accept the answer /vote+, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it. However, the osv file is still very messy to look at when opened in excel. The text is in the wrong columns etc...

Comment: Surprising, I have just used it to download over a million tweets on COVID (took a long time) - it works perfectly well. .csv opens as it should - try using the `library(rtweet) .... `method above

Comment: Very strange that it works for you but not for me. I have tried the library(tweet) method above. It looks perfect in R. All the columns contain the correct information. However, as soon as the csv file it converted into Excel it gets all messed up. Kind of an issue as I need to do simple random sampling of the tweets for a content analysis.

Comment: I finally found a solution! When I open the csv file in LibreOffice instead of excel it looks just fine!

Comment: Unusual, but glad it worked out! Also check if it is not just a viewing issue in Excel: Unless you are using Wordwrap /similar, text from one cell appears to run into the RHS when the RHS cell/s are empty. If so, that's just a viewing issue, the structure remains OK for analysis.

Comment: Might be a viewing issue in Excel. I will look into that. Btw. do you know how I specify the language? I tried putting 'lang= "en"', but it still downloads tweets that are not in English...